# One Way Authentication Client-Server in Java

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, keystore

I am studying the TLS/SSL. I have two snippets of code: Client and Server. I have a problem that the 'One Way Authentication' don't function. In fact if I delete the keystore, they exchange the message without errors. I read on internet that I have to set the check of the certification, but I did understand well.

Maybe I have to set this line `sslServerSocket.setNeedClientAuth(true);` but I have problem with cipher.

Here are the codes:

***Server***

```
// Writing SSL Server in JAVA
public class SSLServerExample {

    // Keystore information
    final static String pathToStore = "C:\\Users\\Manuel\\Documents\\Eclipse_Workspace\\SSLServerExample\\keystore\\"; // Directory
    final static String keyStoreFile = "server.jks"; // Filename
    final static String password = "password"; // Password

    // Port to list SSL Connections
    final static int theServerPort = 12345;

    // Turn on SSL Debugging
    final static boolean debug = false;

    // Server side
    void doServerSide() throws Exception {

        SSLServerSocketFactory sslssf = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLServerSocket sslServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslssf.createServerSocket(theServerPort);

        //JJ
        sslServerSocket.setNeedClientAuth(false);

        // Algoritmi di cifratura che il server accetta di scambiare
        String[] cipherSuites = sslssf.getSupportedCipherSuites();
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cipherSuites));

        final String[] enabledCipherSuites = cipherSuites;
        sslServerSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(enabledCipherSuites);

        // Server is UP
        SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslServerSocket.accept();
        InputStream sslIS = sslSocket.getInputStream();

        // For writing back to the client
        OutputStream sslOS = sslSocket.getOutputStream();

        // Read from the Client
        BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sslIS));
        String string = null;
        while ((string = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(string);
            System.out.flush();
        }
        sslSocket.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String keyFilename = pathToStore + keyStoreFile;
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keytStore", keyFilename);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", password);
        System.out.println("Server connection...waiting client message \n ");
        if (debug) {
            System.setProperty("javax.net.degub", "all");
        }
        new SSLServerExample().doServerSide();
    }    
}
```

***Client***

```
// Writing SSL Client in JAVA
public class SSLClientExample {

    // Truststore information
    final static String pathToStore = "C:\\Users\\Manuel\\Documents\\Eclipse_Workspace\\SSLClientExample\\truststore\\"; // Directory
    final static String trustStoreFile = "truststore.jks"; // Filename
    final static String password = "password"; // Password

    // Where is the Server and the port
    final static String theServerName = "localhost";
    final static int theServerPort = 12345;

    // Turn on SSL Debugging
    final static boolean debug = false;

    // Client side
    void doClientSide() throws Exception {

        SSLSocketFactory sslsf = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslsf.createSocket(theServerName, theServerPort); 

        // Algoritmi di cifratura che il client decide si scambiare
        String[] cipherSuites = sslsf.getSupportedCipherSuites();
        final String[] enabledCipherSuites = cipherSuites;
        sslSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(enabledCipherSuites);

        OutputStream sslOS = sslSocket.getOutputStream();
        sslOS.write("Hello SSL Server...I'm client".getBytes()); // Write to the Server
        System.out.println("I sent a message to the server");
        sslOS.flush();
        sslSocket.close();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String trustFilename = pathToStore + trustStoreFile;
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustFilename);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", password);
        System.out.println("Client...");
        if (debug) {
            System.setProperty("javax.net.degub", "all");
        }

        new SSLClientExample().doClientSide();
    }
}
```